# Dendrogram in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dendrogram

I need to create a dendrogram as in the image below:

[image]

I have a hierarchy of data which consists of Division->Category->Department->Class->SubClass and I need to show the relationship in the visualisation using dendrogram.

My Client is very keen in about the graph. So couldn't go ahead with the dendrogram which is created using node links and sankey.

Comment: What are you stuck on in particular? We generally like posters to start off the process of writing some code, using whatever documentation or existing examples are available, and then help from there. You may find this question will therefore close as being "too broad". Can you add some more detail, or try something and then show that?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what your question is; however, if you are trying to make something like in the image in Tableau, the closest I have seen would be doing something like what is described here: https://community.tableau.com/thread/153509?start=0&tstart=0